# B-spline algorithm

Tags: c#, bspline

I have code for drawing Bezier curves. Is it posible to modify this code for drawing B-Spline curves?

Here is my code using DeCasteljau algorithm:

```
    private Point getPoint(int r, int i, double t)
    {
        if (r == 0) return points[i];

        Point p1 = getPoint(r - 1, i, t);
        Point p2 = getPoint(r - 1, i + 1, t);

        return new Point((int)((1 - t) * p1.X + t * p2.X), (int)((1 - t) * p1.Y + t * p2.Y));
    }
```

I found this code for B-Spline curves. It looks similar to my code, but I have XY points and there are only numbers. I don't know how to modify my code. I tried something but it doesn't work.

```
private double BasisFunction(int k, int i, ParameterCollection u, double t){
if(k==0)
 {
  if((u[i]<=t) && (t<=u[i+1]))
   return 1;
  else
   return 0;
 }
 else
{
 double memb1, memb2;
  if(u[i+k]==u[i])
   memb1 = 0;
  else
   memb1 = ((t-u[i])/(u[i+k]-u[i]))*BasisFunction(k-1, i, u, t);
  if(u[i+k+1]==u[i+1])
   memb2 = 0;
  else
   memb2 = ((u[i+k+1]-t)/(u[i+k+1]-u[i+1]))*BasisFunction(k-1, i+1, u, t);
  return memb1+memb2;
 }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: B-Spline algorithms are more difficult than Bézier algorithms. I don't recommend to copy & paste parts of the methods from different sources. The are several ways to compute B-Splines. If you copy & paste from different sources you will end with code that doesn't work together. I suggest that you look for a copy of Les Piegl's and Wayne Tiller's book "The NURBS book". It contains pseudo code of all necessary functions to compute a point of a B-Spline. The code samples can be easily modified to work in C#.

Comment: The generalization of De Causteljau's algorithm for b-splines is [De Boor's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor's_algorithm). The basis function is basically the weight of a control point on the curve point. You get the curve point by averaging all control points with their respective weights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function BasisFunction() is for computing the value of B-spline basis function N(n,i)(t), where n is degree and i ranges from 0 to (m-1) with m is the number of control points. So, to use this function, you need to define the following for your B-spline:

- degree.
- m control points, denoting them as P[i][2] with i=0~(m-1)
- knot sequence. This is the input "ParameterCollection" to the BasisFunction. You need to have (m+degree+1) knots in the knot sequence and the knot values need to be monotonically non-decreasing. An example of knot sequence for degree 3 B-spline with 5 control points is [0,0,0,0,u0,1,1,1,1], where u0 is any value between [0,1].

Then you can evaluate any point on the B-spline curve at parameter t by something like:

```
double point[2]={0.0}; // point on the B-spline curve
for (int ii=0; ii < m; ii++)  // loop thru all control points
{
    double basisVal = BasisFunction(degree, ii, knotSequence, t);

    point[0] += P[ii][0]*basisVal;
    point[1] += P[ii][1]*basisVal;
}
```